# Reporting Services Chart - Custom Axis Label

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SQL Server Reporting Services (2008) chart (error chart). The X-axis has date intervals 1/1/2009, 2/1/2009, etc. The Y-axis has numeric intervals of 50. Values on the Y-axis are 0, 50 and 100. However, instead of displaying 0, 50 and 100 i would like to display  "Small","Medium" and "Large" respectively. Does anyone know how this text replacement can be performed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but here goes:

1. First, normalize your values around zero, so the smallest value is -50 and the largest value is 50. You can do this in the chart control itself, no need to change your dataset. Your values are between 0 and 100, so just subtract 50.
2. Next, under value axis properties -> axis options, set your minimum to -50, maximum to 50, and interval to 50.
3. Finally, under value axis properties -> Number, select Category as "Custom" and enter this in as the custom format expression: ="Large;Small;Medium"

(that's an excel format code: *pos*;*neg*;*zero*)

You should get something like this:

[alt text http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/9011/chartz.png](http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/9011/chartz.png)

Comment: Thank you so much - that was KILLING me. Can this be done for more than 3 labels (not that I need to do so)?

Comment: No, the Excel format codes are pos;neg;zero. You can omit the zero for just pos;neg. If you need more than three, you will have to suppress the actual y-axis labeling and use a table control to simulate one (yes, it's rather fragile). This is slightly old but it will give you some ideas: 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964128.aspx

Comment: also, I haven't tried it myself, but I imagine ordinary textboxes might work, if the overlapping controls don't cause their own problems.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Arbitrary Label for Y axis in SSRS Charts](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ba0b0f85-7244-4d74-b360-0be663667251/), you can achieve the similar effect by using strip line collection. See [How to: Highlight Chart Data by Adding Strip Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281363.aspx).