# Show percentages in SSRS without "%" character

Tags: reporting-services

I have a graph in an SSRS report that shows percentages. I achieved this my putting a format value of `0.0%`. The database contains fraction values as `0.1` and `0.15` so they get formated as `10%` and `15%` automatically. The business guys don't want the the "%" sign to show.

I can't figure out how to multiple the number by 100 in the format expresion. I think i'm in on of those block moments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it as simple as:

```
=Fields!YourField.Value * 100
```

Or perhaps

```
=Format(Fields!YourField.Value * 100, 0.0)
```

Comment: Great!! Any idea about how to acomplish the same thing in the Y-Axis lables. Using the same format expresion does not work.

Comment: Normally I'd tell you to open a new question to perhaps earn some more rep, but it looks like this question has already been asked and answered. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942086/reporting-services-chart-custom-axis-label