# How to pivot a line graph in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, business-intelligence

I have the following dataset:

[image]

Which creates the following line graph with Roletype as the category group and experience as the value:

[image]

How can I pivot this graph so Roletype is on the y axis and values are on the x axis?

Comment: You need to use bar charts. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239361.aspx

Comment: I am trying to measure a curve so a bar graph won't help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are actually using an area chart rather than a line chart, but both function the same way.  The y-axis measures a numerical value.  You indicate what is on the y-axis by placing something in the values area. If you use a field that isn't a number, it's going to try to sum it or count it or aggregate it in some way. You should use a different chart type to effectively display non-numerical data (see [this article](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/04/19/chart-selection-process/) about choosing the correct chart type). If you want to assign values to your role-types and then display the description on the axis you could do that. I wouldn't necessarily recommend it as an effective way to communicate your message.

To show use the values for the y-axis, add the role-type values field to your dataset.  Use that in the values for your chart and aggregate by avg. Follow the instructions in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942086/reporting-services-chart-custom-axis-label).  You basically set the number type for your vertical axis labels to custom and then add the list of possible values. This only works if you know exactly what values you are expecting.

Comment: Hey sorry about the delay yeah the data that I'm trying to represent is a bit unusual - so it is a strange use of a line graph. However I managed to get it working by reading up on the link that you provided. Thanks :)